# Shift tick label in 3D plot in python

Tags: python, axis-labels

In my figure it is not immediately clear to which dash at the axis my values belong, it needs a closer look. I want it to be clear right away.

Now I have added in red to which they belong. When the values are shifted a little bit upwards I think it will be more clear.

[image: This explains my problem]

This is my code

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x =  np.arange(1950,2010,1)
y = np.arange(0, 50,1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zs = np.array([fun(y,x) for x,y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)

ax.view_init(25,-30)
plt.xlabel('Year')

plt.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: Note, if you drag the image it will rotate, obviously it would still need to line up for different angles.

Comment: I understand, but I only need the figure for that view. So I only want it to happen for that particular view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution would be to make use of the [`tick_params`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html?highlight=tick_params#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.tick_params) function on the `Axes3D` object as follows:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.minorticks_on()
ax.tick_params(axis='both', width=10, labelsize=10, pad=0)

x =  np.arange(1950,2010,1)
y = np.arange(0, 50,1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zs = np.array([fun(y,x) for x,y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
ax.view_init(25,-30)
plt.xlabel('Year')

plt.show()
```

In particular, the `tick_params` function has a `pad` parameter to control the distance. Unfortunately, this does not seem to be fully implemented yet:

> Note
>
> While this function is currently implemented, the core part of the
>   Axes3D object may ignore some of these settings. Future releases will
>   fix this. Priority will be given to those who file bugs.